# Trying to use Javascript to add new li element to my ordered list, anyone know why this code isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This is my HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Fruit Self</h1>
    <ol id=”fruits”></ol>
        Pick a fruit:
    <input type="text" id="newfruit">
    <h1>Basket</h1>
    <ol id=”basket”></ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript File

```
function myFunction()
{
    var newElement = document.createElement("li");
    newElement.textContent = "I am new";
    var ol = document.getElementById("fruits");
    ol.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

I'm trying to use JavaScript to add a new `<li>` element to my `<ol>` fruits. Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Please define "isn't working".  What your code is supposed to do? What is the expected result? What you get instead? When an where are you calling the function?

Comment: What errors do you get? What happens when you step through the code in the fully-featured debugger built into your browser?

Comment: Also, mind your quotes. `”` is **not** the correct quote for an HTML attribute. `"` is.

Comment: you don't even show where you ever call that function

Comment: But the fundamental problem is that you've *defined* a function, but you never call it, so the code inside it never runs.

Comment: I want it to add 'I am new' as a new line item (<li>) under the ordered list (fruits).

Comment: I don't see any code calling the method. `myFunction()`

Comment: I remove the function but doesn't work either

Comment: @MikeSmith: *"I remove the function but doesn't work either"* Why would **removing** the function work?

Comment: Fix your quote issue and call the function and it appears to work https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hp463qzs/

Answer (score 1):

Some problems there:

1. You've *defined* a function, but you never call it, so the code inside it never runs.
2. If you ran it from the script where you have the `script` tag, it would fail because the elements wouldn't exist yet.
3. `”` is not the correct quote for an HTML attribute. `"` is.

If you move your `script` tag to the end of the body, just before the closing `</body>` tag, fix the quotes, and you call the function, it works:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");
  newElement.textContent = "I am new";
  var ol = document.getElementById("fruits");
  ol.appendChild(newElement);
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<h1>Fruit Self</h1>
<ol id="fruits"></ol>
Pick a fruit:
<input type="text" id="newfruit">
<h1>Basket</h1>
<ol id="basket"></ol>
```

As a non-snippet for clarity:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Fruit Self</h1>
    <ol id="fruits"></ol>
        Pick a fruit:
    <input type="text" id="newfruit">
    <h1>Basket</h1>
    <ol id="basket"></ol>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
function myFunction() {
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");
  newElement.textContent = "I am new";
  var ol = document.getElementById("fruits");
  ol.appendChild(newElement);
}
myFunction();
```

---

Side note: You can and should leave the `type` off your `script` tag. The default is JavaScript.

Comment: @j08691: I am. :-) If you *ran* `myFunction` in that script block where it is in the question, the `getElementById("fruits")` would return `null`, causing an exception on the next line.

Comment: Hi thank you so much, my biggest problem was the quotes. I coped and pasted that code from my proffessor and I guessed there was some problem there. Anyways thank you thank you!